# Only to other for Notifications

Tags: laravel

I want to broadcast a **Notification**(not Event) to all subscribers except for the current user like method 'toOthers' in trait InteractsWithSockets for events

Comment: Can you achieve broadcasting notification to all users all together with current user, that part went well with no issue?

Comment: you can achieve that unless the current user to fireup the notification to be broadcast, you just simply add a statement to not include the user on the subscriber